# After check out a page, edit the page and save. Warning prompt the same user have checked out the page

Tags: check-out, save

In one of site collection at our SP2013 farm, we have "SharePoint Server Publishing" site feature and "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" site collection feature activated.

One of user (UserA) create a page (which is a custom content type page) in a page library. The new page is marked as "checked out by UserA". It is fine.

Then UserA open the page -> edit page -> key in something and "save". Then the page prompt him "The file Pages/subfolder/test001.aspx has been modified by i:0#.w|test\userA on 8Aug2014 xx:xx:xx" and ask him to choose "Leave this page" or "stay at this page".  The date time is exactly the time userA was editing the page.

Whatever he choose, the update is saved and browser return to "View" mode (non-edit mode).

It is not the only problem. When userA want to edit the same page again and save, it prompt him that "The page could not be saved because your changes conflict with recent changes made by another user. If you continue, your changes will be lost."!

When userA choose continue or "check out". Follow screen show up:
[image]

What can we do?

Comment: anyone find the solution for this issue?

Comment: I solved it by re-create the page template. The original page template is built at SP2010 and reserved after we upgrade to SP2013. I believe some old code cause the problem but I cannot identity. Therefore I cannot share here.

Answer (score 0):

is user a ddmpdev? if you want to start fresh than overwite the page would reject previous changes. Its not until you publish the page that it would be properly saved for all to see. When you save the page its saving those ammendments just for that user so when he/she comes back to make more changes they can until they either set it to draft, minor or major...

if its the same user making the ammendment, then to save the page and returning to make further ammendments to get that message than that is somthing else.

i think this error is based on the fact that the aspx page is stored within a list on sharepoint and the item is checked out to a specific user. Also could be the fact that its a custom aspx page where you could have custom code that is opening multiple list items that become in conflict resulting in the same error.

Comment: Regardless which user perform the save action, the user encountered the same error (you are locked by yourself so you cannot save)